# Check if a transition will be applied to an element

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I am using CSS transitions to animate the removal of an element from the screen. In FireFox I use the "transitionend" event to detect when the transition is complete and then remove it from the DOM. This only works however if an transition actually occurs.

How can I tell, from JavaScript, whether the change in a property will ultimately result in a "transitionend" event being sent? If there is no transition then I must remove the element directly.

For clarity, I wish to know whether a change in property will trigger an event or not (FireFox is fine for now). This is because I need to trigger an action at the end of the transition, and if there will be no transition I need to trigger it immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the equivalents for `transitionend` for the major vendors (that support transitions):

- Webkit: `webkitTransitionEnd`
- Opera: `oTransitionEnd`
- IE and Mozilla: `transitionend`

To find out whether the property is being animated, simply check if it has reached the destination value immediately:

```
el = $('myElement');
el.css('top', '100px');
if(!el.css('top') == '100px'){
    alert('No transition');
}
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/6Q9XC/

Comment: I'm not asking for the various browser equivalents, I'm asking whether I can detect if the event will occur at all.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y I've added a demonstration of what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Modernizr docs](http://modernizr.com/docs/#hasevent), I'm assuming you could just:

```
Modernizr.hasEvent('transitionEnd', $element)
```

Comment: Actually scratch that, [there's a bug specifically with transitionend](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/322)